# tinymce adds p tags around content and stores it in database, when I retrieve with PHP, what's best way to split the p tag and add a class to each

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, tinymce

Tinymce stores something like this in database:

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

When I retrieve from database, I would to extract each instance of

and add a class to it:

```
<p class='hello_world'>Hello World</p>
```

I think I got it to work:

```
    if ( ! function_exists('tinymce_tag')){
    function tinymce_tag($content = ''){

        $pos = strpos($content, '<p>');

        if($pos !== false){
            $content = substr_replace($content,' class="paragraph"', 2, 0);
            return  $content;
        }
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: do you get a different result in anyother browser like IE ?

Comment: I reasked the question given the fact that I realize the initial one was cuased by p tags stored in database that was conflicting with the html helper that was creating p tags on top of the existing p tags. But in the end, all I am trying to do is add a class to these p tags on the fly.

Comment: Do you need the same class for each <p>? If not, what's the criteria for determining  what class each one gets?

Comment: Why dont you use javascript/jquery for that ?

Comment: I would rather use php than javascript for creating html like this.

Comment: If it's the same class for all <p> tags, why not just wrap the TinyMCE output in a container div, and reference it with something like this: `#container p { color: red }`? Or have I misunderstood the question? I'm good at that :-D

Comment: I dont think adding a div is necessary. I just want to add a class to all the paragraphs. I have 90 percent of the function finished. It's just rendering as plain text not html.

Comment: why don't u try the php parser down below?

Answer (score 1):

You can try a php parser like [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) one

Comment: +1 I think this is helpful but perhaps a little too much for the simple task I was doing above, which I eventually got to work by removing the htmlspecialchars function.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that you use `htmlspecialchars()`. This changes it from HTML to plain text. Just remove this function call and it will be html code.

Comment: +1 I actually realized that the same time you were probably writing this answer.

Comment: If that's the right answer for you, could you accept it? thanks :)